# JTwitter access token and access token secret

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, jtwitter

I'm writing the application which has Twitter integration (JTwitter + OAuthSignpost). I'm able to update a status within my own account by supplying consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, and accessTokenSecret. But how can I update a status from another account? From where should I retrieve that specific user access token and access token secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorising an account is a manual process.

Do you have the password for the other account? You need that to authorise (obviously you can't post as other people without a security check!). Then it's the same as for your own account. JTwitter creates a url, you direct the user (e.g. yourself) to visit that url in a browser, where Twitter will check you want to give the authorisation. Then eithe

First (in your browser) login to twitter.com as the account you want to authorise. Then go through the process of getting an authorisation token for JTwitter.

If you're building a website or an Android app, then it would be the website user who goes through this process.